# Div spacing problem

Tags: css

I am trying to space out DIVs. I have five DIVs that are 30px wide and want to put these into another DIV that is 150px wide. Sounds simple but I find the five DIVs don't fit.

5*30 = 150 (but it requires a 166px outer div for them to fit inline)

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SLq6z/)

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B" >a</div>
    <div class="B" >b</div>
    <div class="B" >c</div>
    <div class="B" >d</div>        
    <div class="B" >e</div>
    <div class="B" >f</div>
</div>

div.A { background-color: Red; width: 150px;}
div.B { display: inline-block; height: 20px; width: 30px;}
```

Is there something I am missing? I can't understand why the browsers space the way they do.

Comment: You've got 6 divs there, buddy.

Comment: I'm watching the first five to see when they wrap around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are turning the divs into inline elements, the other inline content will also come into play, i.e. the white space between the elements. You get a space between each div, which takes up a few pixels more.

If you remove the white space between the divs, there will be no spaces between them, and five elements fit in 150 pixels:

http://jsfiddle.net/SLq6z/1/

Answer (score 0):

Can you replace `display:inline-block` with `float:left` without causing any other issues? it solves your current problem...

```
div.B { float:left; height: 20px; width: 30px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` property for both your classes A and B ;).